# How to check if Googlebot is crawling and indexing my site?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

My site URL is like `example.com/html/Project` I had put the Google Analytics code snippet on this site.  After doing so, I'm started looking for this URL in Google, but it is not showing.

Actually, I want to see that my page is being crawled by in Google. Just to make sure I didn't mess up the meta noindex for security reasons.

Comment: Add a property in Google Search Console. Make sure it is how you want your site to appear in search such as www.example.com. It is always a good idea to add properties for www.example.com, example.com both HTTP and HTTPS just in case. That is 4 properties. Keep in mind that both GA and GSC can take some days to start to work properly. So be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created the search console account and verified it with one of the methods provided also upload a sitemap and verify it. Also you need to create entries for all the instances like said above.